# \tcolorboxenvironment incompatible with hbox?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

The following MWE fails with the error message `\begin{tcolorbox} on input line 10 ended by \end{foo}`. Removing the option `hbox` leads to succes, though of course without the desired effect of reducing the box to the smallest possible width.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{foo}{begin}{end}
\tcolorboxenvironment{foo}{hbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
  asdf
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug or intended behavior? I could not find anything about it in the documentation. If it is not a bug, is there any way to get around this?

---

(In reality, my environment is a bit more complex, of course, which is why I don't just use `\newtcolorbox`. The main issue preventing me from doing so is that it has several optional arguments like `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{ O{one} O{two} }{begin with #1 and #2}{end}` and I want the color box environment to also be a `tabular` environment. In any case, the question stands, as applications where one wants to box an environment from a package (without wanting to touch the package code) would run into the same issue.)

Comment: Environment `foo` is inheriting `\textwidth`, and tcb is just wrapping itself as minimally around `foo` as possible (before `hbox` option even starts throwing its braces around and unbalances things). Need to reduce `foo`s width to actual text width somehow, like `\mbox` does. Perhaps a savebox and calculate actual width. Will `foo` be multi-line, multi-paragraph?

Comment: @Cicada I'm not sure I get what you mean. The content of `foo` is only (attempted to be) typeset _after_ the `hbox` option kicks in. The issue here is that `tcolorbox` tries to capture its content looking for `\end{tcolorbox}` which isn't in the input stream (yet). See also the corresponding [bug report](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/154).

Comment: I was thinking to get the natural width of `foo`'s text (and not `foo`'s width of `\textwidth`) and bypass `hbox` option altogether. Manually adjusting `\textwidth` before `foo`'s use, shrinks `foo`, for example, and the tcb follows suite.

Comment: @Cicada So you're saying, we should replicate what `hbox` usually does? (Capturing the environment content in a box before typesetting the `tcolorbox` around it?) Also, I'm still confused about what you mean by "`foo`'s width of `\textwidth`". Nothing in `foo` ever gets to be `\textwidth` wide in this MWE. (In fact, nothing inside `foo` gets typeset at all.) `\textwidth` is just an unused value here.

Comment: Raising the issue with the package maintainer is the best way. I was just examining the behaviour of `foo` and the tcb *without* hbox option, to get a baseline. That part is interesting but really is a different MWE, and your question specifically relates to using hbox option, so apologies for confusing matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\tcolorboxenvironment` is currently only compatible with the `capture` mode `minipage` (the default), not with `hbox` or `fitbox`. An enhancement extending it to those other modes [is being worked on](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/154) and will likely be included in the next version (4.52).

Until then, the workaround is to collect the environment body first and then insert `\begin{tcolorbox}` and `\end{tcolorbox}` in the same expansion step (i.e. in the begin code of the environment). This can be done using `xparse`'s `b` argument type (ore using `environ` if you want to be old-fashioned).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{ +b }{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[hbox]
    begin%
    #1%
    end%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
  asdf
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{wrappedtcb}{ m O{} +b }{ \begin{tcolorbox}[hbox,#2] \begin{#1} #3 \end{#1} \end{tcolorbox}}{}` would be more flexible. Noted the `+` in `+b` to accept `b` long.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks for that note, I made the example long and just included the `tcolorbox` in the definition of `foo`; that's what the original goal was, after all (giving `foo` a `tcolorbox` without needing to change its use in the document).

Answer (score 0):

This way it works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%\newenvironment{foo}{begin}{end}
%\tcolorboxenvironment{foo}{hbox}

\newtcolorbox{foo}{hbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
  asdf
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, if using `\newtcolorbox` were an option, this would work. I just used a trivial environment to keep the example minimal. I elaborated a bit on this in the question.